# PHP doesn't seem to be processing script to post to MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using html5 canvas to capture a signature and store it in MySQL. I've got everything in the script working except for the part that saves the signature and sends it to MySQL. 
My knowledge of AJAX is none so I'm working off what I read in books, see on tutorials and get help on from here.

So in Firefox console when I click on save signature I can see the script displays the post.php file it's supposed to go to and displays a 200 ok notification but nothing happens, it doesn't post in MySQL (which doesn't surprise me as I'm sure my code is incorrect) and I don't see any errors.

What I want to accomplish is to upload the signature image to a folder on the server and save the path to the image in MySQL. Being unfamiliar with JavaScript, Jquery and Ajax I'm confused with how to get this to function.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/** Set Canvas Size **/
var canvasWidth = 400;
var canvasHeight = 75;

/** IE SUPPORT **/
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('signaturePad');
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;

/** Redraw the Canvas **/
function redraw() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width; // Clears the canvas

    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    context.lineJoin = "miter";
    context.lineWidth = 2;

    for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
            context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
        } else {
            context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
        }
        context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
    }
}

/** Save Canvas **/
$("#saveSig").click(function saveSig() {
    //encode URI
    var sigData = encodeURIComponent(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
$("#imgData").html('Thank you! Your signature was saved');
    var ajax = XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", 'post.php');
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
    ajax.send(sigData);
   // $('#debug').html(sigData);
});

/** Clear Canvas **/
$('#clearSig').click(
    function clearSig() {
        clickX = new Array();
        clickY = new Array();
        clickDrag = new Array();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});

/**Draw when moving over Canvas **/
$('#signaturePad').mousemove(function (e) {
    if (paint) {
        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
        redraw();
    }
});

/**Stop Drawing on Mouseup **/
$('#signaturePad').mouseup(function (e) {
    paint = false;
});

/** Starting a Click **/
function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
    clickX.push(x);
    clickY.push(y);
    clickDrag.push(dragging);
}

$('#signaturePad').mousedown(function (e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    paint = true;
    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
    redraw();
});

});
```

and here is the PHP: Also I didn't write the php code below it's part of the entire signature pad so I'm sure it's not correct.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
$session_id = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// Get the data
$imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

// Remove the headers (data:,) part.
// A real application should use them according to needs such as to check image type
$filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

// Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;
$imageName = "sign_" . rand(5,1000) . rand(1, 10) . rand(10000, 150000) . rand(1500,   100000000) . ".png";
//Set the absolute path to your folder (i.e. /usr/home/your-domain/your-folder/
$filepath = "xampp/htdocs/alpha/site7/images/" . $imageName;

$fp = fopen("$filepath", 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
fclose( $fp );

//Connect to a mySQL database and store the user's information so you can link to it later
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root', 'password') OR DIE(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db("customer", $link);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'signature' ('session', 'image_location') VALUES       ('$session_id', '$imageName')") OR DIE(mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

And the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Signature Pad</title>

<!-- The Signature Pad -->
<script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="signature-pad.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<fieldset style="width: 435px">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="signaturePad" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; height: 55px; width: 400px;"></div>
    <br/>
    <button id="clearSig" type="button">Clear Signature</button>&nbsp;
    <button id="saveSig" type="button">Save Signature</button>
    <div id="imgData"></div>
    <div 
    <br/>
    <br/>
</fieldset>
</center>
<div id="debug"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

After some head beating over this I've finally been able to discover some errors. 
After signing the signature pad and pressing the save signature button I get these errors in Firebug

> **Warning**:  fopen(xampp/htdocs/alpha/site6/images/sign_42281643871777767.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\alpha\site6\post.php** on line **20**
>   
>   **Warning**:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\alpha\site6\post.php** on line **21**
>   
>   **Warning**:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\alpha\site6\post.php** on line **22**
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''signatures' ('session', 'image_location') VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 'sign_42281643871' at line 1

Since I don't have any knowledge of Jquery or Ajax and how they are creating the image and attempting to post it to a folder I'm pretty much stuck at this point!

Comment: some basic debugging would go a long way

Comment: just a side note....you have jquery loaded...why not use the $.ajax() functions provided by Jquery

Comment: You forgot `session_start()` at top in `php` file.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar forgot to remove the session part, at this time I don't want to use sessions, I'm just trying to get the signature image uploaded to the server and path stored in MySQL. I'm just trying to figure out how this works so I can get a basic understanding. That said, even with the session_start() at the top it still wont post to MySQL

Comment: @KyleK that's why I'm asking for help, I'm fairly new to all this and I'm looking for some guidance on how to do it. Everything I've read and watched isn't clear enough for me to figure out how this script is posting the image. If it was as simple as putting the path to a folder to save the image to I could figure it out but evidentally it's not.

Comment: @Dagon but where do I begin debugging? I know the script works as I can draw on the canvas, clear the signature and when the save signature button is pressed I can see it call up the process.php script but after that nothing happens.

Comment: First solve the `fopen` warning, it tells you that most likely the directory you try to write in, does not exist. If you sloved this `fwrite` and `fclose` should go away, because these errors are a result of the `fopen`. Then php tells you that your SQL syntax has an error, so check whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems I'm answering my own problems, I've figured out what the fopen errors were, I wasn't using an absolute path so adding a / before the start of the path cleared up everything except for the last error of this:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''signature' ('session', 'image_location') VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 'sign_11814198867' at line 1

Comment: Read about the difference between `'` quotes and `\`` quotes in mysql. One is for table/column identifiers and the others about quoting values.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, I'm aware of the difference between single quotes, double quotes and back ticks. I wasn't paying attention to the quotes as I was concentrating on other things, I've got it working now that I removed the quotes it's posting to the database and uploading the image to the folder. Thanks for your input!